# Degree of $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[80]{43},\sqrt[84]{43})/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to calculate the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[80]{43},\sqrt[84]{43})/\mathbb{Q}$.

I think the formulas $X^{80}-43$ ie. $X^{84}-43$ solve the equations. But I don't know how I can use this information to my advantage

Answer (score 7):

If $L$ is the field in question, we see that $L$ contains $$43^{\frac{c}{80} + \frac{d}{84}} = 43^{\frac{80c + 84d}{80\cdot 84}}$$ for any integers $c,d$. In particular, $L$ contains $43^{4/(80\cdot 84)} = 43^{1/1680}$. It is now clear that $L = \mathbb Q(43^{1/1680})$, since $43^{1/80}, 43^{1/84}$ are both powers of $43^{1/1680}$. Since $X^{1680}-43$ is irreducible (by Eisenstein's criterion, for example), the degree of this extension is $1680 = \text{lcm}(80,84)$.

More generally, if we had $\mathbb Q(43^{1/a_1},\dots, 43^{1/a_n})$, we would find via essentially the exact same argument that the degree of this extension is $\text{lcm}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Comment: Very nice and lucid  answer!